How to skip vars_prompt if variables exist within import_playbook?
I have this playbook script to execute some basic task on the switch and firewall.
Requirement :

Case 1. User need to execute the parent script to perform all basic
task on child 1 and child 2.
Case 2. User need to execute directly
on the child 1 to perform basic task.
Case 3. User need to execute
directly on the child 2 to perform basic task.

Information :

Parent script host only localhost.
Child 1 script hosts are multiple switch.
Child 2 script hosts are multiple firewall.

Parent : test_dummy_sw_fw.yml
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
    - name: ansible_user
      prompt: "Enter Username"
      private: no
    - name: ansible_password
      prompt: "Enter Password"
      private: yes

- name: Execute Script on Switch
  import_playbook: test_dummy_sw.yml

- name: Execute Script on Firewall
  import_playbook: test_dummy_fw.yml

Child 1 / Switch : test_dummy_sw.yml
- hosts: Switch
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  
  vars_prompt:
    - name: ansible_user
      prompt: "Enter Username"
      private: no
    - name: ansible_password
      prompt: "Enter Password"
      private: yes
  
  tasks:
    - name: Interface Config
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - description Testing Switch
        parents: "interface Gi0/0"  
      register: print_output

    - debug: var=print_output

Child 2 / Firewall : test_dummy_fw.yml
- hosts: Firewall
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  
  vars_prompt:
    - name: ansible_user
      prompt: "Enter Username"
      private: no
    - name: ansible_password
      prompt: "Enter Password"
      private: yes
  
  tasks:
    - name: Interface Config
      asa_config:
        lines:
          - description Testing Firewall
        parents: "interface Ethernet1"  
      register: print_output

    - debug: var=print_output

I want to create a script to skip the prompt when a variable has been set in a parent playbook. I've also tried this on the playbook, but Ansible still prompts for the variable in the child playbook.
Parent :
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
    - name: ansible_user
      prompt: "Enter Username"
      private: no
    - name: ansible_password
      prompt: "Enter Password"
      private: yes

  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      ansible_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      ansible_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"

- name: Execute Script on Switch
  import_playbook: test_dummy_switch.yml
  vars:
    ansible_user: "{{ ansible_user|d('default') }}"
    ansible_password: "{{ ansible_password|d('default') }}"
        
- name: Execute Script on Firewall
  import_playbook: test_dummy_fw.yml
  vars:
    ansible_user: "{{ ansible_user|d('default') }}"
    ansible_password: "{{ ansible_password|d('default') }}"

Is there any way to ensure that Ansible recognizes that the variable already exists and skips the prompt without using extra variables ? Because the requirement of this script are only needed to prompt once for username and password.

In imported playbooks, use pause conditionally.

Ok, let me explore the pause modules.

Thanks to Vladimir Botka, i got some inspiration from his answer.
Its been resolved using the script below.
Parent Script : test_dummy_sw_fw.yml
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: "Enter Username (Local/TACACS)"
      private: no
    - name: password
      prompt: "Enter Password"
      private: yes

  tasks:
  
  - set_fact:
        ansible_user: "{{ username }}"
        ansible_password: "{{ password }}"

# Test Script on Switch

- name: Execute Script on Switch
  import_playbook: test_dummy_switch.yml
    
# Test Script on Firewall

- name: Execute Script on Firewall
  import_playbook: test_dummy_fw.yml

Child 1 / Switch : test_dummy_sw.yml
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  pre_tasks:

    - when: ansible_user is undefined
      block:
        - pause:
            prompt: Enter Username (Local/TACACS)
          register: username
        - set_fact: ansible_user="{{ username.user_input }}"

    - when: ansible_password is undefined
      block:
        - pause:
            prompt: Enter Password
            echo: false
          register: password
        - set_fact: ansible_password="{{password.user_input }}"
    
- hosts: Switch
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        ansible_user: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['ansible_user'] }}"
        ansible_password: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['ansible_password'] }}"
    
    - name: Interface up/down - SDL1
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - description Testing Switch
        parents: "interface Gi0/0"    
      register: print_output
      
    - debug: var=print_output

 

Child 2 / Firewall : test_dummy_fw.yml
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  pre_tasks:

    - when: ansible_user is undefined
      block:
        - pause:
            prompt: Enter Username (Local/TACACS)
          register: username
        - set_fact: ansible_user="{{ username.user_input }}"

    - when: ansible_password is undefined
      block:
        - pause:
            prompt: Enter Password
            echo: false
          register: password
        - set_fact: ansible_password="{{password.user_input }}"

- hosts: Firewall
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  
  vars_files:
    - if_dummy_asa.yml

  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        ansible_user: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['ansible_user'] }}"
        ansible_password: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['ansible_password'] }}"

    - name: Interface Config on Firewall
      asa_config:
        lines:
          - description Testing Firewall
        parents: "interface Ethernet1"  
      register: print_output

    - debug: var=print_output

When we executed the Ansible script on parents it will only prompt the credentials once because the credentials has been set previously on Parent Script, so prompt will be ignored on child script.
When we executed directly on child there will be a prompt since the credentials of ansible_user and ansible_password is not defined on parents.

For example, given the inventory
shell> cat hosts
[sw]
test_01
test_02

[fw]
test_03

Run the first play on all hosts and set the task run_once: true. This will "instantiate" the variables at all hosts

shell> cat pb1.yml
- hosts: all

  vars_prompt:

    - name: ansible_user
      prompt: Enter Username
      private: false
    - name: ansible_password
      prompt: Enter Password
      private: true

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        ansible_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        ansible_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
      run_once: true

- import_playbook: pb2.yml
- import_playbook: pb3.yml



In the imported playbooks, set the pre_tasks run_once: true

shell> cat pb2.yml
- hosts: sw

  pre_tasks:

    - when: ansible_user|length == 0
      run_once: true
      block:
        - pause:
            prompt: Enter Username
          register: out
        - set_fact:
            ansible_user: "{{ out.user_input }}"

    - when: ansible_password|length == 0
      run_once: true
      block:
        - pause:
            prompt: Enter Password
            echo: false
          register: out
        - set_fact:
            ansible_password: "{{ out.user_input }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_user: {{ ansible_user }}
          ansible_password: {{ ansible_password }}



The third play pb3.yml, for testing, is identical with pb2.yml with changed hosts only

shell> cat pb3.yml
- hosts: fw
  ...


shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml
Enter Username: 
Enter Password: 

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01]

PLAY [sw] ***********************************************************************************************************
[pause]
Enter Username:

TASK [pause] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01]
[pause]
Enter Password (output is hidden):

TASK [pause] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_user: user_sw
    ansible_password: pswd_sw
ok: [test_02] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_user: user_sw
    ansible_password: pswd_sw

PLAY [fw] ***********************************************************************************************************
[pause]
Enter Username:

TASK [pause] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_03]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_03]
[pause]
Enter Password (output is hidden):

TASK [pause] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_03]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_03]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_03] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_user: user_fw
    ansible_password: pswd_fw

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
test_01                    : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_02                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_03                    : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   



I added new examples. Make sure you understand all implications of run_once.
